# Clarification on Includes in DLLs

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, include

I recently came across something that goes against my understanding of includes.

I am creating a dll to hold basic coordinate objects for a personal game engine I'm developing (for fun).

Main dll header file.

```
#pragma once

#include "sclapi.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "point.h"
// Other includes and stuff.
// Unimportant for this demonstration.
```

sclapi.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef SCL_EXPORTS
#define SCL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SCL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

vector.h

```
#pragma once

// No includes

/*EDIT*/struct Point;

struct SCL_API Vector {
    float x, y;

    // Other stuff

    explicit operator Point() const;
};
```

point.h

```
#pragma once

// No includes

struct SCL_API Point {
    int x, y;

    // Other stuff

    explicit operator Vector() const;
};
```

My code works perfectly fine; but to my understanding, it shouldn't. A header file should only know what's declared in it (includes being shorthand for pasting in code). None of these objects are declared in the other's header files. [EDITED] point.h should have no knowledge of a Vector struct. Whats more, both even have knowledge of the SCL_API macro. If I comment out individual includes in the main header file, I get the expected compiler errors. What am I missing?

EDIT:

After further testing, I discovered that a declaration of the later objects needs to be in the first header file 'vector.h'; but after, they do not need to be declared again in any other header file. Also, declaring the classes in the main header file does not work. The Point forward declaration must be inside the vector.h file.

Comment: With the forward declaration no magic is going on. This is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you `#include` a file, it gets automatically "copypasted" into your source.
Because you included `vector.h` right before including `point.h`, the `Point` class will see it. 
However, it's not a good idea to rely on this behavior as the order of includes might change and thus it will not work anymore, so you should `#include "vector.h"` in your `point.h`.